# Как отобразить иконку в listview

Tags: c#, winforms

Всем здравствуйте, подскажите как отобразить иконку в Listview. У меня есть класс,в котором я получаю данные для отображения,есть сама форма, иконку саму я получаю, но не отображается и все тут. Благодарен за помощь

```
// сам класс где создаются данные для отображения.
public class Controller
{
    public  List<info> PrintKeys(string rkey)
    {
        List<info> stroka=new List<info>();
        bool F = true;
        bool G = true;
        String rp = rkey;
        RegistryKey rk;
        using (rk = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(rp))
        {
            var e = rk.GetValueNames().Select(n => new
            {
                Name = n,
                Value = rk.GetValue(n),
                Exec = rk.GetValue(n).ToString()
                    .Split('"').Where(i => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(i)).First()
            });
            foreach (var x in e)
            {
                var icon1 = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(x.Exec).ToBitmap();
                stroka.Add(new info() { A = icon1, F1 = F,G1 = G,Namefile1 = x.Name, Path1 = x.Value});
            }
        }
        return stroka;
    }
}

//вот класс самой формы
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Controller c=new Controller(); 

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listView1.Items.Clear();

        string r1 = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run"; // реестр local mashin
        string r2 = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run"; //реестр СCurren user
        string rp3 = @".DEFAULT\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run"; //реестр user 

        List<info> a = c.PrintKeys(r1);

        for (int i = 0; i < a.Count; i++)
        {
            listView1.Items.Add(a[i].Namefile1);
            listView1.Items[i].SubItems.Add((string) a[i].Path1);
            listView1.Items[i].SubItems.Add(a[i].F1.ToString());
            listView1.Items[i].SubItems.Add(a[i].G1.ToString());

            // и вот тут не работает, свойство А хранит в себе уже битмаповскую иконку
            listView1.Items[i].ImageList.Images.Add(a[i].A);
        }
    }
}

//И сам класс для данных
public class info
{
    public Bitmap A { get; set; } // иконка файла
    public string Namefile1 { get; set; } //Имя исполняемого файла.
    //public string C1 { get; private set; } //Параметры командной строки для запуска файла.
    public object Path1 { get; set; }// путь
    public bool F1 { get; set; }//Флаг наличия цифровой подписи.
    public bool G1 { get; set; }//Флаг корректности цифровой подписи

    public info() { }
}
```

Comment: Мой совет будет состоять из 3-х букв: WPF

Comment: @LiptonDev спасибо, уже перехожу на него.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы не указываете значение свойства [ListViewItem.ImageIndex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.imageindex(v=vs.110).aspx) или [ListViewItem.ImageKey](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.imagekey(v=vs.110).aspx), обратите внимание на тот факт, что эти свойства взаимоисключающие, т.е. если явно указано одно - второе будет сброшено в значение по-умолчанию (-1 или "" соответственно).

Измените немного логику заполнения ListView. Например так:

```
//Перед циклом создадим новый список изображений.
//По умолчанию они отсутствуют в ListView
var imList = new ImageList();
listView.LargeImageList = imList;
listView.SmallImageList = imList;

for (int i = 0; i < a.Count; i++)
{
    listView1.Items.Add(a[i].Namefile1);
    listView1.Items[i].SubItems.Add((string) a[i].Path1);
    listView1.Items[i].SubItems.Add(a[i].F1.ToString());
    listView1.Items[i].SubItems.Add(a[i].G1.ToString());
    //добавляем изображение с ключом в список
    imList.Images.Add(key: a[i].Namefile1, image: a[i].A);
    //указываем ключ для отображения картинки
    listView1.Items[i].ImageKey = a[i].Namefile1;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо  заработало, но почему то так сложно, пойду в wpf))

Comment: @VladimrVladimirovoch там свои сложности, не считая погружения в MVVM, так что сильно легче не станет, пробуйте, сравнивайте =)